# Install certificate in login keychain with swift 3 on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, certificate

I have a cocoa project, building a MacOS app. I won't distribute it on Apple store.

What should I use in Swift 3 to install a certificate in the login keychain, to be always trusted, like this command does ?

```
security add-trusted-cert -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db ca-cert.cer
```

I already have my ca-cert.cer and ca-cert.pem created.

I know about the Authorization API and I saw in Apple documentation this method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1401659-secitemadd 
and this doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/certificates/storing_a_certificate_in_the_keychain

First I create a der version of my pem with

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in ~/ca-cert.pem -out ~/ca-cert.der
```

Then The following code will successfully install certificate in login keychain but won't be trusted.

```
    do {
        let cerData = NSData(contentsOfFile: homeDirURL.path + "/ca-cert.der")
        let certificate: SecCertificate? = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, cerData as! CFData)
        let addquery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate,
                                       kSecValueRef as String: certificate,
                                       kSecAttrLabel as String: "My Certificate"]
        let status = SecItemAdd(addquery as CFDictionary, nil)
        guard status == errSecSuccess else {
            print("error \(status) : " + (SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil) as! String))
            return
        }

    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
    }
```

What should I change for it to be always trusted ?

Answer (score 3):

In objective c, you need to do the following steps.

//Your certificate have already been installed in login.keychain by using SecItemAdd

```
SecCertificateRef certificate; //use SecCertificateCreateWithData to get it.

NSDictionary *newTrustSettings = @{(id)kSecTrustSettingResult:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kSecTrustSettingsResultTrustRoot]};

SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings(certificate, kSecTrustSettingDomainUser, (__bridget CFTypeRef)newTrustSettings));
```

Note that i type this by hand, so check type errors by yourself.

I have tested it by myself, so what you need to do is you change it to swift code.